# Xamarin.Forms. Collectionview adds a lot of extra white space after its content

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, collectionview

I would like there to be no empty space after the content of the collection view.

I tried to put my button in footer but then i ran into problem that property isenabled = false is not being applied to it in my code behind.
Here is my xaml file:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <RefreshView x:DataType="local:QuestionViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <views:MyTextView LaTeX="{Binding Formulation}" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="15, 10, 15, 0"/>
                <!--<RefreshView x:DataType="local:QuestionViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">-->
                    <CollectionView
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Answers, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedAnswers, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        SelectionMode="Multiple"
                        x:Name="collectionView"
                        SelectionChanged="collectionView_SelectionChanged"
                        >
                        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                            <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"/>
                        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Answer">
                            <StackLayout Padding="10">
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState Name="Normal">
                                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                                <Setter TargetName="frame" Property="Frame.BackgroundColor" Value="{Binding AnswerColor}"/>
                                            </VisualState.Setters>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState Name="Selected">
                                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                                <Setter TargetName="frame" Property="Frame.BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource MainColor}"/>
                                                <Setter TargetName="label" Property="views:MyTextView.TextColor" Value="White"/>
                                            </VisualState.Setters>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <Frame CornerRadius="10" HasShadow="True" x:Name="frame" BackgroundColor="{Binding AnswerColor}">
                                    <views:MyTextView x:Name="label" LaTeX="{Binding Content}" />
                                </Frame>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
                <!--</RefreshView>-->
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label x:Name="conditionLabel" TextColor="{DynamicResource AnswerColor}"/>
                    <Button x:Name="checkButton" Text="Проверить ответы" CornerRadius="10" Margin="10"
                                Command="{Binding CheckAnswersCommand}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RefreshView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Result:
[1 part of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6djx5.png)
[2 part of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNF8d.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a known problem, and an [open issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6451).

See that thread for possible work-arounds. And to track any progress on fixing it.

Bottom line: you have to manually specify/calculate height. There are multiple ways to do so, of various difficulty. Thread mentions some. You would need to Google for more details.

One quick-and-dirty solution I like, when acceptable, is to wrap CollectionView in Grid, and then use RowDefinitions to force how much height is given to row containing CollectionView, how much to everything else. Something like:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <CollectionView Grid.Row="0" ...>
        ...
    </CollectionView>

    <StackLayout Grid.Row = "1" ...>
        ... everything that is below the CV ...
    </StackLayout>
 </Grid>
```

This would restrict row 0 (which contains CollectionView) to top 1/3 of screen.

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't use Listview/Collection View with in Scrollview as described in official documentation.

There is an alternative to listview within Scrollview. Look at following code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScrollViewDemos"
             x:Class="ScrollViewDemos.Views.ColorListPage"
             Title="ScrollView demo">
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{x:Static local:NamedColor.All}">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <BoxView Color="{Binding Color}"
                                 HeightRequest="32"
                                 WidthRequest="32"
                                 VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding FriendlyName}"
                               FontSize="24"
                               VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Follow Documentation for more support:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scrollview

Comment: I've tracked down my horrible performance issues to using a stacklayout with bindablelayout.itemtemplate like this. I have a CarouselView I use to swipe between two views. The first carousel itemtemplate has buttons, the second similar to your suggestion. Buttons work fine, but swipe to the stacklayout, then swipe back and buttons are incredibly laggy. Just changing the Stacklayout-bindablelayout to be a CollectionView and it's snappy again. But then I have the space at the bottom issue. ugh. Can't win.
Everyone thinks "simple, just do this!!" but it undoes something else.